# jQuery Plug In not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

So I am trying to use a jQuery plugin to create a pagination effect as seen on http://www.florianwacker.de/en/

I found a link to a plugin at http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

It seems very straight forward, but I cannot get it to work.

Here is the HTML

```
<head>
    <title>Aldi Rebrand</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fullPage.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="red">
    <div id="navBar">
        <a href="index.html"><img id="navLogo" src="images/navLogo.png"></a>
        <ul>
            <li class = "navLink mainLink"><a href="index.html">Work</a></li>
            <li class = "navLink mainLink"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li class = "navLink mainLink"><a href="https://ggann.tumblr.com">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <div id="fullpage">
            <div class="section">
                <div id="aldiPhoto"></div>
                <div id="descriptionAldi">
                    <h2>ALDI Rebrand <span>BRANDING | LOGO | PRINT</span></h2>
                    <p class="intro"><strong>ALDI</strong> is an international grocer, spanning from Germany to The United States and many other countries around the world.</p>
                    <p class="prjctDescription">The premise behind this semester long project was to immerse ourselves in the company/brand we were assigned. I was assigned ALDI. In this scenario, the goal of the rebrand was to convey a new “fresh and local” side to ALDI and their proposed farmers market addition to their stores. We were asked to create a brand new logo, at least four pieces of collateral and a brand guideline to demonstrate our research, branding applications and flexibility.</p>
                    <div class="btnDiv">
                        <a href="https://dribbble.com/shots/1869394-ALDI-Rebrand" class="btnText"><div class="btn1"><p>VIEW ON DRIBBBLE</p></div></a>
                        <a href="https://www.behance.net/gallery/22556203/ALDI-Rebrand" class="btnText"><div class="btn2"><p>VIEW ON BEHANCE</p></div></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <div id="aldiPage2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <div id="aldiPage3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="ticker"><p class="currentPage">1</p><div class="tickerBtm"><p class="maxPage">3</p></div></div>
</body>
```

And here is my css for my site

```
a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
body.red {
    background-color: #d04b47;
}
div {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 10em;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: .85em;
}
h2 {
    color: #d04b47;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: .85em;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
h2 span {
    color: #b1b3b6;
    font-size: .25em;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
section {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
}
/* BLOG POST TALL CONCEPT */
h2.blgHead {
    color: #d04b47;
    font-size: 3em; 
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
h2.blgHead span {
    color: #b1b3b6;
    font-size: .25em;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.blgDescription {
    color: #000000;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: .75em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.blgIntro {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.blogPostTall {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}
.btn1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    border: solid #d04b47 2px;
    width: 12em;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease; /* Opera */
}
.btn1:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 9%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    border: solid #d04b47 2px;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    width: 13em;
}
.btn2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    border: solid #d04b47 2px;
    width: 12em;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease; /* Opera */
}
.btn2:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-right: 9%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    border: solid #d04b47 2px;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    width: 13em;
}
.btnDiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.btnText {
    color: #d04b47;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.description {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.intro {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.prjctDescription {
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.category {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=(50));
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-weight: 100;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease; /* Opera */
}
.category:hover {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=(100));
    opacity: 1;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.galleryImg {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    padding: 0px;
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}
.hidden {
    opacity: 0.25;
}
.mainLink {
    font-size: .85em;
    font-weight: 800;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease; /* Opera */
}
.navLink {
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 22px;
}
.currentPage {
    margin-bottom: .25em;
    margin-left: .5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
    margin-top: .5em;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.maxPage {
    margin-bottom: .25em;
    margin-left: .5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
    margin-top: 0em;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.ticker {
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    border: solid #ffffff 2px;
    margin: 1.5em;
    padding: 0px;
}
.tickerBtm {
    width: 1.5em;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    border-top: solid #ffffff 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: .5em;
}
#aboutPhoto {
    background-image: url(../images/Red2.jpg);
    background-position: top,left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#aldiPhoto {
    background-image: url(../images/aldiLarge.jpg);
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#aldiPage2 {
    background-image: url(../images/aldiPattern.jpg);
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#aldiPage3 {
    background-image: url(../images/Jar1.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#aldi {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    padding: 0px;
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}
#createathon {
    clear: both;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    padding: 0px;
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}
#description {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #d04b47;
}
#descriptionAldi {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#elloPhoto {
    background-image: url(../images/Ello.gif);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#everlane {
    clear: both;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    padding: 0px;
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}
#fincher {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    padding: 0px;
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}
#fincherPhoto {
    background-image: url(../images/fincher1.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#fincherPage2 {
    background-image: url(../images/fincher3.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#fincherPage3 {
    background-image: url(../images/fincher4.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#fincherPage4 {
    background-image: url(../images/fincher5.jpg);
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#fincherPage5 {
    background-image: url(../images/fincher6.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#fincherPage6 {
    background-image: url(../images/fincher7.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#fincherPage7 {
    background-image: url(../images/fincher8.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#fincherPage8 {
    background-image: url(../images/fincher9.gif);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#mobmail {
    clear: both;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    padding: 0px;
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}
#myLogo {
    clear: inherit;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    padding: 0px;
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}
#navBar {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    -moz-transition: all .25s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all .25s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all .25s; /* Opera */
}
#navBar.scroll {
    margin-top: -48px;
}
#navBar.scroll:hover{
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#navLogo {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}
#pact {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    padding: 0px;
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}
#rcfPhoto {
    background-image: url(../images/rcf1.JPG);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#rcfPage2 {
    background-image: url(../images/rcf2.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#rcfPage3 {
    background-image: url(../images/rcf3.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#rcfPage4 {
    background-image: url(../images/rcf4.JPG);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #d04b47;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

I used the provided css and js files as you can see in the head of my html. For whatever reason, the page behaves as if there is only the first section and the other two "sections" just aren't displayed at all.

I just don't see how I went wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

Switch script including order, put jquery.js as the top of jquery.fullPage.js. Try something like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just copied your rest of code into FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/3vjxpw7z/. Could you please check it? thanks.

Comment: I feel so silly... I left a piece of code in my js file from a previous plugin I tried to use and it was interfering, everything is working. Thank you for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: Actually, I do have a new problem. I have a small tidbit of javascript that I was using to make the navigation bar on my page slide up when scrolling down the page. Now that this plugin is working properly, the browser isn't technically scrolling down, so that bit of code doesn't trigger the nav to move up off the page. I am using an if/else if/else to add a "hidden" class when the browser scrolls down past "y > 0". How can I make this effect still work in this situation?